# Asp Classic fill table with SQL database returns

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have ASP classic code with SQL statement that returns two columns data which I need to fill a table.

I make a call to the function below, it connects to the database, but the challenge is on how feed the returned data into the table. I may need to do some sort of "do while", this is where I got stuck, I could use some directions or guidance:)

```
Function FillTable()

    Msg_Body = Msg_Body & "
" & vbCrLf
    Msg_Body = Msg_Body & "" & vbCrLf
    Msg_Body = Msg_Body & "" & vbCrLf    
   sql = " Select distinct a.column1 as ColumnName, count(a.column1) as TotalCount " & vbCrLf
   sql = sql & " from table1 a, table2 c, table1_type d, sprt_sc_folder e  " & vbCrLf
   sql = sql & " WHERE a.column1 = b.column2 " & vbCrLf
   sql = sql & " group by a.column1 " & vbCrLf
   response.write("Column_Count:
" & sql & "

")
    set rs = connP15.Execute(sql)

    Column_Name = rs("ColumnName")
    Total_Count = rs("TotalCounts")

End Function
```

Comment: Here are the bits you need to combine: A `While`/`Wend` loop, the `rs.EOF` property, the `rs.Fields` collection and the `rs.MoveNext()` method. This should give you enough keywords to read and research for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to put this table into `Msg_Body`, or do you want to display it on the screen, or do you want the function to return the table as its value, or ...?

```vbs
Function FillTable()
    dim t
   '...
    set rs = connP15.Execute(sql)
    t = "<table><tr><th>Column</th><th>Count</th></tr>"
    Do Until rs.EOF
        t = t & "<tr>"
        t = t & "<td>" & rs("ColumnName") & "</td>"
        t = t & "<td>" & rs("TotalCount") & "</td>"
        t = t & "</tr>"
        rs.Movenext '<-- very, very important! (well, unless you like hung servers)
    Loop
    t = t & "</table>"
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    FillTable = t
End Function
```

Instead of the `Do...Loop`, you could try something with `rs.GetString...`, but in my experience, it loves to add blank rows/columns at the end, which you then have to remove somehow, so unless you're returning thousands of rows and/or hundreds of columns, it's just not worth it.

Comment: It entirely depends on the queried object you use with `GetString()` I've always found it to be very effective and having to loop it yourself is pointless and cumbersome. Also a fan of `GetRows()` for enumerating recordsets as Arrays allowing the database connection to be closed quickly rather then having to navigate a clumsy overbearing object that has an active connection with the database.

Comment: @Lankymart: oh, there's no question that `GetRows` is the way to go if you need to put a recordset into an array, but because of the extra rows/columns problem, the same can't really be said for `GetString`. (I suppose it's possible that the problem only occurs with MS SQL Server, but since that's what we use...)

Comment: I am able to get it to work using your suggestion. I made some changes to meet my need and I all ready to go:)